# Trouble Parsing an XML file using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have a code written to parse an XML file in ruby using 'nokogiri' gem. However the logic that i have currently goes and fetches an entire nodeset but what i really want i to do is go fetch the value of an particular attribute in the nodeset. Need some help on how to achieve this using nokogiri???

This is my XML:

```
<page1>
    <testno>3414 & 3413</testno>
    <testdesc>New Design Testing</testdesc>
    <clientname>Meridian Bioscience</clientname>
    <clientaddress1>3471 River Hills Road</clientaddress1>
    <clientaddress2>Cincinnati, OH 45244</clientaddress2>
    <TestRequestedBy>Ginger Powell</TestRequestedBy>
    <DatePrepared>September 3, 2014</DatePrepared>
</page1>
```

Comment: @SachinSingh The Ruby code can be accessed at http://pastie.org/private/10asqxjotr2uyliubcliyw

Comment: @SachinSingh  The xml Listing can be accessed at http://pastie.org/private/2lzzdvuu0djebilhpslcoq. Now I need to access value present in each attribute inside page1 block seperately, like say testno, testdesc. etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
***file.xml***

<page1>
    <testno>3414 & 3413</testno>
    <testdesc>New Design Testing</testdesc>
    <clientname>Meridian Bioscience</clientname>
    <clientaddress1>3471 River Hills Road</clientaddress1>
    <clientaddress2>Cincinnati, OH 45244</clientaddress2>
    <TestRequestedBy>Ginger Powell</TestRequestedBy>
    <DatePrepared>September 3, 2014</DatePrepared>
</page1>
```

require 'nokogiri'

doc = File.open("file.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

doc.xpath("//page1").each do |item|

```
    p item.at('testno').text
    p item.at('testdesc').text
    p item.at('clientname').text
    p item.at('clientaddress1').text
    p item.at('clientaddress2').text
    p item.at('TestRequestedBy').text
    p item.at('DatePrepared').text
```

end

Answer (score 0):

First require 'nokogiri' in your class.

To access the value of all the child elements. I have stored it in array finally.

```
elements = []
xml_string = "<page1>
    <testno>3414 & 3413</testno>
    <testdesc>New Design Testing</testdesc>
    <clientname>Meridian Bioscience</clientname>
    <clientaddress1>3471 River Hills Road</clientaddress1>
    <clientaddress2>Cincinnati, OH 45244</clientaddress2>
    <TestRequestedBy>Ginger Powell</TestRequestedBy>
    <DatePrepared>September 3, 2014</DatePrepared>
</page1>"

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_string)
parent_node = doc.xpath("//page1")

parent_node.each do |child_element|
 elements << child_element.text.gsub("\n","")
end

p elements
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Is there any way you know how to loop through all the elements present inside the 'page1' tag using nokogiri, Can you edit your code to achieve the same

Comment: Hey can you help me what would be the best way for me to access these values in the ruby code I have included as a  part of my question?